# What are the tradeoffs of reusing a cursor vs. creating a new cursor?

Tags: python, sql, database, oracle, cx-oracle

In cx_Oracle (or Oracle in general), is it possible to allocate a cursor for each query, or to reuse a cursor across several queries.

```
def getSomeData(curs):         # case 1: pass in a cursor, which is generally
    curs.execute('select ...') #         reused across queries
    return curs.fetchall()

def getSomeData(conn):         # case 2: pass in a connection,allocate
    curs=conn.cursor()         #         a cursor for this query
    curs.execute('select ...')
    return curs.fetchall()
```

Of course, both approaches return the same data.

What are the tradeoffs between the two approaches?  Is one particularly more or less efficient?  Are there any potential pitfalls to reusing a cursor over many queries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can re-use a cx_Oracle cursor as much as you like, no problem. If you're executing thousands of small queries in a small space of time, you *might* see a slight performance improvement by re-using the cursor, but I doubt it.

I will sometimes create new cursors, and other times re-use an existing one, depending on whether it makes the code easier to read and understand.

For example, if I have a variety of procedures that need to access the database, I might pass an Oracle connection object around, or a cursor created on that connection.

Whatever makes your code more readable and easier to maintain is what I'd go for.